# Ordering of operators in 2nd Quantization of the Tight Binding Model

Tags: operators, second-quantization, tight-binding

I am looking at the position space representation of the Tight Binding Hamiltonian (without the spin component and ignoring any constants) as given by:

$$\hat H = \sum_{i}\sum_{\delta}(\hat c_{i}^{\dagger} \hat c_{i+\delta} + \hat c_{i+\delta}^{\dagger}\hat c_{i})$$

During the first step to get the momentum space representation, it is given as:

$$\hat H = \sum_{i}\sum_{\delta,k,k'}(e^{-ikr_{i}}e^{ik'(r_{i}+\delta)}\hat c_{k}^{\dagger} \hat c_{k'} + e^{-ik'(r_{i}+\delta)}e^{ikr_{i}}\hat c_{k}^{\dagger}\hat c_{k'}) = ......$$

My question is this. Why isn't the ordering of the operators in the 2nd term above be $\hat c_{k'}^{\dagger}\hat c_{k}$ instead of $\hat c_{k}^{\dagger}\hat c_{k'}$? I am asking this because the 2nd term in the position space representation is the Hermitian Conjugate of the 1st. So shouldn't the ordering of the operators also swap when it comes to the momentum space representation?

Comment: $k,k'$ are dummy variables, so they do not have to have the same names in the second term as in the first. The whole Hamiltonian must me hermitian conjugate, but it is not required for each term in the sum.

Comment: Hmmm... no? Because there are different exponential terms infront so the ordering of the operators does matter?

Comment: Ok so I evaluated the summation and got the same result at the end. So the ordering of the operators does not matter.

Comment: Ordering remains always the same: they are normal ordered (creation operator is on the left)

Comment: I mean, $\hat c_{i}^{\dagger}$ and $\hat c_{i}$ are associated with $\hat c_{k}^{\dagger}$ and $\hat c_{k}$ respectively. Similarly, $\hat c_{i+\delta}^{\dagger}$ and $\hat c_{i+\delta}$ are associate with $\hat c_{k'}^{\dagger}$ and $\hat c_{k'}$ respectively. So by direct substitution to $\hat c_{i+\delta}^{\dagger} \hat c_{i}$, shouldn't it be associated with $\hat c_{k'}^{\dagger} \hat c_{k}$?